# Using Entity Framework in EC2 gives EntityException

Tags: .net, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When trying to run a LINQ query while being hosted in EC2 (AWS) I get:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.

Same code works on programing environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible issues:
One - Installation of sql client for the entity ADO .net.
In my case, although I installed it before fixing the second issue - I don't think it was really missing.. just wanted to make sure.

Two - EC2 firewall (I think this was the issue in my case). - the sql server has to have a rule to allow internal incoming communication on the sql server port.
Please note that the external IP address did not work for me - I had to use the sg-XXXX.. set for these rules.
(My SQL Server is also hosted in AWS..)

Comment: I received this error, tried again and there was no error.

Comment: This worked for me for a Web API project but does not work for a Dynamic Data website..